# Fetching App level and Global level settings from DB

Tags: mysql

I am building a dynamic application which will act based on settings.

The settings are stored in a MySQL table which consists of both App level data and global level data `(app_id = 0)`.

My use case is, I want to select the settings of an App. If it does not exist, fetch the corresponding setting from the global level.

I have achieved this using sub queries and `COALESCE` function.

**Question:** Can the data be fetched in a single query? If not, Can the schema be modified to handle this App level and Global level in a much simpler way?

**Schema**

```
CREATE TABLE `settings` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `partner_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `app_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `type` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
    `name` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
    `value` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    KEY `key_partner_id` (`partner_id`),
    KEY `key_app_id` (`app_id`),
    KEY `key_type` (`type`),
    KEY `key_name` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**Data**

```
| id | partner_id | app_id |  type |    name |  value |
|----|------------|--------|-------|---------|--------|
|  1 |        500 |      0 | color | primary |   blue |
|  2 |        500 |    100 | color | primary |  green |
|  3 |        500 |    101 | color | primary |    red |
```

**query**

```
SELECT * FROM settings WHERE app_id in (
  COALESCE ((SELECT app_id FROM settings WHERE app_id = 100), 0)
);

| id | partner_id | app_id |  type |    name | value |
|----|------------|--------|-------|---------|-------|
|  2 |        500 |    100 | color | primary | green |


SELECT * FROM settings WHERE app_id in (
  COALESCE ((SELECT app_id FROM settings WHERE app_id = 102), 0)
);

| id | partner_id | app_id |  type |    name | value |
|----|------------|--------|-------|---------|-------|
|  1 |        500 |      0 | color | primary |  blue |
```

Comment: It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!

Comment: @MEE Yes, I completely accept your point, but if I ask three different questions with the same context, wont it duplicate the whole thing ?

Comment: ok, it would probably duplicate the whole thing, but the problam is that this question is basically three questions: `How can I fetch data from these tables in one query?`, `How can I modify the table to reduce queries?` and `How to improve the App level, Global level segregation?`. At least the first question is on-topic (IMO), not sure about the others. In the current form the question is probably too broad. So I am not sure what to do, either.

Answer (score 0):

Single query to get the settings for the app or fall back on global settings

```
SELECT * FROM settings 
WHERE app_id IN(0,102)
ORDER BY app_id DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Obviously, this assumes a single row for the app settings.